# Why does RNGCryptoServiceProvider's constructor ignore its parameter?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I saw this while coding and thought it seemed odd:

[image]

Sure enough, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3dh7bhb(v=vs.110).aspx) says that `RNGCryptoServiceProvider(byte[] rgb)` and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider(string str)` both ignore their parameters. 
As far as I can tell, there is no practical difference between either of those two and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()`. What is going on? I suspect I'm missing something weird to do with cryptography.

Comment: What would you expect the argument to be used for?

Comment: @NikBougalis I would expect one of two things; either the argument would be a seed value or they wouldn't provide useless constructors. As neither of those are true, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a leftover from a previous older version, maybe going back as far as 1.x as even the 2.0 API contains the same description. It could however well be that the 2.0 and 2.1 API's have changed in the mean time.

If you look at the Mono source then you find

```
_handle = RngInitialize (rgb);
```

and

```
_handle = RngInitialize (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (str));
```

so I presume that the data was used as an additional or initial seed for a platform provided random number generator. That would also make the most sense. The Mono source usually follows the MS implementation as much as possible.

If the platform provided RNG is secure there may be little need to seed it from an application. Using an RNG as method to generate the same stream over and over again (i.e. when the parameter is used as initial seed) is fraught with danger, especially if the underlying implementation is unknown and may differ between platform and system updates. So that would be a good reason to deprecate the constructors.

Obviously if they are just deleted then the old sources won't compile anymore. So it is more logical to leave the implementation empty as the resulting instance should be generating random data anyway.

---

In the end this is just a (very) educated guess though, the reason is not specified in the current API documentation. The constructors are not marked obsolete either it seems. Everything I've come to expect from Microsofts crypto API documentation in other words.